# set online user while user view a mp4 video

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm using the code below to return a mp4 video to the user, and I want to update the last activity of the user while the user sees the video.  I thought to use the second code below to update, but the js not run if I return the video.

PHP Code:

```
$file_name = 'path/to/video.mp4';
$file_size = (string)(filesize($file_name));
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: '.$file_size);
header("Content-Disposition: inline;");
header("Content-Range: bytes .$file_size");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
header('Connection: close');
readfile($file_name);
```

JS Code:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(updateLastActivity, 10000);
    function updateLastActivity(){
        $.post("./sys/api.php", {option: "update_last_activity", user_id: "'.$user['id'].'", channel_id: "'.$channel['id'].'", user_agent: "'.$user_agent.'", user_ip: "'.$user_ip0.'"}).done(function(response) {}, "json");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: why not run the update code in the php before returning the file?

Comment: ^ this. Apart from that solution: where is the js code located? In the same file?

Comment: because the code needs to be executed every 10 seconds, the js code it's in the same file

Comment: if the browser is serving the file, it cant run the js at the same time. if the file is opened in another application, then it can. and just because the js is updating a table doesn't actually mean the user is active. This level of user tracking is very inaccurate.

Comment: What would be the best solution to my problem ?

Comment: Your best solution would be to track if the user is actually playing the video using JS. A complete list of events can be found [here](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#media-elements-event-summary)

Comment: i need return the direct video

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result I needed with this code, now just need to call the method of updating the last activity by an async method.

```
$file_name = "path/to/mp4/file.mp4";
$file_size = (string)(filesize($file_name));
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: $file_size");
header("Content-Disposition: inline;");
header("Content-Range: bytes $file_size");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Connection: close");

$user_agent = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : 'not_found';
$user_ip = (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : 'not_found';

ob_clean();
ob_end_flush();

$last_time = 0;
$handle = fopen($file_name, "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
    if(time() > $last_time) {
        $last_time = strtotime("+15 seconds", time());
        /* CALLING THE METHOD TO UPDATE THE LAST ACTIVITY! */
        update_last_activity($user['id'], $channel['id'], $user_agent, $user_ip);
    }
    echo fread($handle, 1000);
}
```